# The servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application is referenced in servlet-mapping, but not defined in web.xml

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, web.xml

I get an error whenever I try to deploy a very basic JAX-RS app on Weblogic 12.1.3.0 server.

I have defined this dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

... and this is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<!--    <servlet> -->
<!--        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name> -->
<!--        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> -->
<!--    </servlet> -->
<!--    <servlet-mapping> -->
<!--        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name> -->
<!--        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern> -->
<!--    </servlet-mapping> -->

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my HelloWorldService.java:

```
package dgcplg.test.hazelcast.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of HelloWorldService
     * @return an instance of String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/get")
    public String sayHelloGET() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I have installed the jax-rs 2.0 included in the WebLogic 12.1.3.0 zip distribution by following Oracle's official docs

What could be the cause of the error?
Please let me know if further info is required.

EDIT: I forgot to add, that inverting the commented lines in the web.xml as shown below it does work though, but I would like to avoid explicit dependency from Jersey if possibile.
Inverted web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- <servlet> -->
    <!-- <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name> -->
    <!-- </servlet> -->
    <!-- <servlet-mapping> -->
    <!-- <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name> -->
    <!-- <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern> -->
    <!-- </servlet-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: An easier way would be just to get rid of the xml (or at least the servlet configuration) and just use Java code. Create a subclass of `Application` an annotate it with `@ApplicationPath("/webapi")`. Not sure why the web.xml isn't working for you though. The config looks fine. Also note, I don't use WebLogic, but one problem I see is that in the web.xml, where it works, you are referencing the Jersey 1.x `ServletContainer`, which means it's using JAX-RS 1.x. If the server does use JAX-RS 1.1, you will have a problem using classes from the 2.0 API. You should check and confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I know that I can subclass Application, but my question is focused at getting my simple webservice to work by using the Application class, as reported by Oracle's Java EE 7 Tutorial. As for the reference to Jersey, that's what I am trying to avoid. As for the JAX-RS 1.x, I installed the jax-rs 2.0 shared library in my WebLogic Server in order to use version 2.0, which is supported in version 12.1.3.0 of WebLogic.

Comment: My concern is why is it still working with the Jersey 1.x ServletContainer. Not sure if it is a strict requirement to use the xml configuration, but an empty `Application` class will give you the same functionality. You don't need to register anything. They will all be scanned. I still don't have an answer for why the xml config doesn't work though. Like I said, it is correct configuration.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. Finally I have got the time to do some other test. I imported the "jersey-container-servlet" (v.2.19) maven dependency and it worked on Tomcat.